# Monitor showing as DVI although plugged in as VGA

Tags: drivers, nvidia, monitor

Recently I had my computer upgraded because I was having problems getting Ubuntu 14.04 to work. I now have more than the min requirements but am still having trouble getting the graphics to work once I install the appropriate NVIDIA driver.  (before that it is really slow and graphics seems to be one leading cause) One of the things that remained the same was our monitor so I have been looking at that more carefully. When I use the command **xrandr**, the results indicate that the connected monitor is DVI-I and that there is no VGA monitors. When I double checked the screen and the back of the computer, both ports are labelled as VGA.

My monitor is a Princeton VL1917 (company is gone, I got it second hand and have not been able to locate a manual on line.)

My graphics card is Nvidia G72 GEForce 7200 6S 7300E therefore I was using the nvidia-304 driver (attempted to download it NVIDIA AND standard repositories)

I am using a fresh install of Edubuntu 14.04.

Currently I am trying to get a hold of a DVI cable to try.

Any input would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Most usage seems to be through the graphics drivers I believe. As I said, this was a fresh install with the following hardware:
Memory : 2GiB
Processor : Intel Core 2 Duo CPU E4600 @ 2.40 GHz x2
OS type 32 bit
Graphics GEForce 7200 GS/7300 E

ALSO, when I just tried a DVI cable, the xrandr command now says that the VGA is hooked up and nothing is connected through the DVI...

Installing the nvidia 304 with the DVI cable still caused non response/black screen problems

Answer (score 0):

I would perhaps look at other causes of slow graphics performance, other than the monitor.

It is quite likely that the issue with graphics performance is due to other causes.

DVI and VGA can readily convert with an appropriate simple adapter.

Try checking also:
- CPU performance
- memory performance
- the types of apps that manifest slow graphics